# How is nature able to know of upcoming dangers?

Tags: mahabharata, nature

I have read in the Mahabharata that at birth, Duryodhana’s nature was shown by some warnings and 'ashubh suchana' (bad omens) like the sound of crying donkeys. So my question is, how is nature able to know of upcoming dangers and show appropriate signs according to that upcoming danger.

Comment: Nature knows everything. Isn't it evident? Nature is Supreme Prakriti. It has all access to Kaala.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar how nature is able to know everything?

Comment: Because it has access to Kaala. Karmic events are prerecorded. Prakriti is no different from Purusha which knows everything and is antaryami.

Comment: What do you mean by coming dangers?

Comment: Omens..known to  cast a shadow before they really appear.

Comment: Nature is always is gving its signals one had to up their antenna to listen to such signals Even animals are more receptive to nature signal in case earthquake they know.. only humans are  constrained by intellect